# Measure word / compound noun for quotas?

Tags: single-word-requests

The sentence is:

> The regulator released new ______ of inbound and outbound quotas this
>   month.

I had tried to fit "batches" here, and that seems to be adequate. But over time I keep looking back at this sentence and raising an eyebrow. I would like to explore other collocations with quota and measure words / compound nouns if such exist.

- tone is formal/professional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think a word is needed here at all. I would say "The regulator released new inbound and outbound quotas this month." The fact that the word "quotas" is plural already indicates that there are multiple. Unless you are meaning to say that he released a handful here and there throughout the month. Then the word "batches" would actually be appropriate.

Comment: I like this solution.  Also possible: Released new figures for inbound and outbound quotas.  Released new values for inbound and outbound quotas.  Released new specs.  Released new sets etc.